# Linq To Xml: Enumeration Yielded No Results

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

This is my xml layout:

```
 <Data>
      <Record />
           <PCI>
                <FirstName></FirstName>
                <LastName></LastName>
           </PCI>
      </Record>
      <Record />
           <PCI>...</PCI>
      </Record>
      <Record />
           <PCI>...</PCI>
      </Record>
</Data>
```

Query I have trying to use:

```
var Data = from Record in queryXml.Descendants("Record")
           select new
           {
              lname = PCI.Element("LastName").Value
           };
```

When debugging the Data variable I get a Enumeration Yielded No Enumeration. I have tried renaming the Data and Record and the input into Descendants method, but I cant find something that works.

Comment: Your XML and your code are both invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a typo, but `<Record/>` will make the record empty. You should say `<Record>`.

Comment: That is the way the it appears from the web service I am using. <Record someattributes="something" /></Record>

Answer (score 0):

You say that is how the xml is returned from the webservice you are using.  That is badly formed xml.  Using your example above:

```
<Data>
  <Record /> //<-- this closes the Record element
       <PCI> //<-- PCI would not be a child of Record, but a child element of Data
            <FirstName></FirstName>
            <LastName></LastName>
       </PCI>
  </Record> //<-- This is invalid as written unless you 
            //  remove the '/' from Record above.
```

Your webservice should return your data this way:

```
 <Data>
  <Record>
       <PCI>
            <FirstName></FirstName>
            <LastName></LastName>
       </PCI>
  </Record>
  <Record>
       <PCI>...</PCI>
  </Record>
  <Record>
       <PCI>...</PCI>
  </Record>
</Data>
```